# Find out the command and location of an installed application

Tags: software-installation

This is very embarrassed. I installed psensor from its source code, but now when I wan t to run it:

```
$ psensor
The program 'psensor' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

I also want to add it to startup applications, so how can I find the location of its executable?

Some information about it is

```
$ dpkg -l psensor
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  psensor        1.0.4-1        psensor-1.0.4 installed from source on oct 1


$ man -k psensor
psensor (1)          - Temperature monitoring application
```

Thanks.

Comment: run `sudo updatedb && locate psensor`

Answer (score 1):

After compiling and installing psensor, if is not in your PATH, it means that you miss the `make install` step or you have use a custom installation location (`./configure --prefix=/installation_path`) which is not in your path.

Usually, to compile and install it on the system, you can use:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr    
make clean all    
sudo make install
```

psensor will be in the `/usr/bin/`.

To autostart psensor, just open the psensor preferences, startup tab, check autostart toggle.